# File Inheritance Structure Possible?

Tags: external-files, folders, tex-general

Is it possible to make a kind of inheritance while working with big projects in LaTeX?

I think of a tree like inheritance where each child (which are tex-files) inherits the packages and commands of the parent but is able to overwrite same package with other options for example?

For Example:

```
%Root.tex
\usepackage{pkg1}
\usepackage[optls]{pkg2}
```

---

```
%child1.tex
\input{Root.tex}
\usepackage{pkg3}
```

---

```
%child2.tex
\input{child1.tex}
\usepackage[newoptls]{pkg2}
```

Be aware, that those files will be in different folders, and all child files are in sub folders of the root file. So there is a command in Latex to set the root path for all files, but I don't remember and can't find.

Comment: basically no, if you include the same package twice with different options latex will issue an error

Comment: Basically. And is there an advanced way?

Comment: Sorry your question isn't specific enough on your real intention.. the answer to your question as written is no but I can't really guess your real need. If the document is a single document spread over multiple files, there  can only be one preamble and one set of packages loaded. If the multiple files are separate documents they can of course have independent preambles.

Comment: Some packages include commands which make it easy to overwrite previously set options. So if your concern is with such a package, you could do something like this but not with `\usepackage`.